# Number key on Logitech keyboard gets stuck sometimes

Tags: keyboard, logitech-keyboard

I have a [Logitech Ultrax Premium keyboard Y-BL49A](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/639/662) and the <kbd>1</kbd> key  sticks sometimes.

I don't know how to pop up keys on this keyboard without breaking them.  I know that on old ones this is easy, but mine is only a little old and seems different.

Comment: Wash it? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F_uCvGYherU Since it is no good, you are not gambling much anyway ;)

Comment: @Johan Watched it. Sorry, but I'm not planing to kill my dishwasher or current keyboard. More logical solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

use WD-40, just a little squirt should work, and being it is a non-conductive solution you wont have to worry about it shorting out any components.

Comment: also... try at your own risk, I cant be held responsible if you break your broken keyboard more. ;)